# Nuxt 3 SSR useFetch refetching data client side

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I am implementing a simple SSR site using useFetch. It works perfectly when the url is an hardcoded string but as soon as I start using the runtime config var (from .env file) the fetch is triggered on the server (successfully) and the on the client side leading to a CORS issue. What could be the issue?

```js
<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

let url = config.BASE_URL || config.public.BASE_URL + route.path;

const { data } = await useFetch(url, {
  headers: {
    fetchMode: 'headless',
  },
  server: true,
});
</script>
```

Please note I had to add both config and public config because of the second fetch on the client side.

Comment: Do you mind sharing which external API you are trying to use on your app? That would be really helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't @ReaganM, it's an internal API that returns json data..as I said everything works fine with an hardcoded string like

let url = 'www.site.com' + route.path;

but it breaks when using the the config var

Comment: Understood. Strange, it should work just fine using the `runtimeConfig`. Perhaps an exact error type and message you are experiencing? That would be helpful for debugging.

Comment: Yeah there isn't a specific error logged. What I can see is that the runtime env BASE_URL is found but it seems like it's overriding route.path and for some reason using this runtime config re-trigger the fetch on the client side...btw thanks for the help with this - appreciated

Comment: Have you tried experimenting? Something like ```await useFetch( `${ useRuntimeConfig().public.BASE_URL }/${ useRoute().path }` )```

Comment: let me try, I am wondering if this works on the server too. As far as I know the public runtime config is not available on the server but I could be wrong, I will give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254730/discussion-between-reaganm-and-alessio-chiffi).

Answer (score 2):

To prevent refetching on client side, u can try to use 'useState' and 'watch:false'

'watch:false' will prevent a refetch if the url or another parameter will change, which might be the case in your example.

```
let result = useState('result');
  result.value = await useFetch(url, {
    headers: {
      fetchMode: 'headless',
    },
    server: true,
    watch: false,
  });
```

from the [Docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/state-management):

> useState: is an SSR-friendly ref replacement. Its value will be
> preserved after server-side rendering (during client-side hydration)
> and shared across all components using a unique key.

from the [Docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#params):

> watch: Watch an array of reactive sources and auto-refresh the fetch result when they change. Fetch options and URL are watched by default. You can completely ignore reactive sources by using watch: false

Comment: Hey Stefan, I have tried according to your comment but is it an appropriate and standard way to use useFetch with ssr?

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya   you can use useFetch with or without ssr. You might want to take a look at the docs for the different data fetching methods: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching

Comment: I have read and implemented according to the doc but when we start the page initially it always returns Failed to fetch and when the same API recalls after component updates then it works perfectly. my node version is v20.9.0 and Nuxt version is 3.11.1 with nitro 2.9.4

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your server to allow requests from your website origin. That doesn't happen on SSR  because CORS is a browser feature. Servers can talk to each other without restrictions (unless you explicitly set up your server to specify who can call it). Browsers on the other hand implement several security features, one of which is CORS.

These links are helpful if you want to better understand what CORS is

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KHiSt0oLJ0
- [Can someone explain to me what is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) in the most simplest terms?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/pzuy6h/comment/hf3wo6t/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
- [Complete Guide to CORS](https://reflectoring.io/complete-guide-to-cors/)
- [Why does CORS exist in websites but not mobile or desktop apps?](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/j2gz3y/why_does_cors_exist_in_websites_but_not_mobile_or/)

Comment: Yep that is right and you explained exactly what was happening. It was as easy as just adding the domain to the cors policy

Comment: Glad it worked, please mark the question as the correct Answer if that's the case